# Error al iniciar SQL

Tags: mysql

**Este es el error al iniciar SQL**

`Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.`

```
systemctl status mysql.service mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-06-15 15:08:52 CEST; 51s ago
Process: 26830 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 15 15:08:52 omgserv-165194 mysql[26830]: Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Jun 15 15:08:52 omgserv-165194 systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 15 15:08:52 omgserv-165194 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Jun 15 15:08:52 omgserv-165194 systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
```

**Este es el log del error**

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f1d90b7f448]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x57f1e5)[0x557b856d91e5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x57fd2e)[0x557b856d9d2e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x64daa2)[
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x643cc8)[0x557b8579dcc8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x581bd5)[0x557b856dbbd5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x572c3c)[0x557b856ccc3c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x577433)[0x557b856d1433]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8064)[0x7f1d92181064]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f1d90c3162d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
180615 14:54:01 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
180615 14:54:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
180615 14:54:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
180615 14:54:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
180615 14:54:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
180615 14:54:01 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
180615 14:54:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
180615 14:54:02 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
180615 14:54:02 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 196250478976
180615 14:54:02  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 196250502868
180615 14:54:02  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 r
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: revisa tu log: /var/log/mysql/error.log

Comment: tambien te sugiero revisar esto: https://askubuntu.com/questions/829772/mysql-failed-to-restart-on-ubuntu-16-04